Why isn't my mirror modifier working when importing my fbx file into Unreal Engine?
For some reason when i'm importing my model of a knife as an fbx file into Unreal Engine it's halved. I used a mirror modifier when i modeled the knife and i made sure to both apply it and check the "Apply modifiers" box before exporting it as an fbx file. Despite my efforts the knife is still halved when i import it.
Does anyone have a solution to my problem?
Here is a picture of the "halved knife":


It looks like your normals are inverted, which gives this x-ray effect on the surface towards camera. You can flip the normals with :

Go to Edit Mode Tab
Select all faces A
Alt+N > Recalculate Outside
Or alternatively Alt+N > Flip if the previous action didn't succeed

